# Matlab can't recognize the numerical range of a function when symbolic variables are used as parameters

Tags: matlab, symbolic-math

Matlab fails to recognize that a function with a numerically defined range always falls in that range when function parameters are defined as symbolic variables. The example below shows the problem for the CDF of a normal distribution. Here is my code:

```
kmax = sym('kmax',{'positive','rational'});
mu = sym('mu',{'positive','rational'});
s = sym('s',{'positive','rational'});
isAlways(normcdf(kmax,mu,s)>=0)
```

which gives the following error:

> Conversion to logical from sym is not possible.
>
> Error in normcdf>localnormcdf (line 127)
> if sigma > 0
>
> Error in normcdf (line 50) [varargout{1:max(1,nargout)}] =
> localnormcdf(uflag,x,varargin{:});

When I try defining CDF manually as in

```
syms ncdf(x);
ncdf(x) = (1/2)*(1+erf((log(x)-mu)/(s*sqrt(2))));
isAlways(ncdf(kmax)>=0)
```

I get this error:

> Warning: Unable to prove '0 <= 1/2 - erf((2^(1/2)*(mu -
> log(kmax)))/(2*s))/2'.
>
> In symengine
>
> In sym/isAlways (line 41)
>
> ans =
>
> logical
>
> 0

Similarly, I cannot show that error function - which has a range [-1,1] - is always greater than or equal to -1, i.e.

```
isAlways(erf(kmax)>=-1)
```

gives

> Warning: Unable to prove '-1 <= erf(kmax)'.
>
> In symengineIn sym/isAlways (line 41)
>
> ans =
>
> logical
>
> 0

Is there a way to overcome this problem? Is there perhaps a function that performs better at evaluating symbolic expressions than `isAlways`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`normcdf`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/normcdf.html) function (part of the Statistics and Machine Learning Toolbox) is a numeric function and as you saw, is not designed for general use with symbolic math. The better approach is to define you own symbolic function as you did.

The issue appear to be with your specification that your variables are `'rational'`. If you remove that, you'll be able to get  the correct answer from `isAlways` for the more general case:

```
syms kmax mu s positive;
syms ncdf(x);
ncdf(x) = (1/2)*(1+erf((log(x)-mu)/(s*sqrt(sym(2)))));
isAlways(ncdf(kmax)>=0)
```

I do not know mathematically why the addition of the `'rational'` assumption would cause `isAlways` to fail other than it may be trying to employ alternative methods for that case. You might ask MathWorks about this or even file a [service request / bug report](https://servicerequest.mathworks.com/mysr/cp_case_new1).

I you need the `'rational'` assumption elsewhere in your code, you can add or remove it via the [`assume`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/sym.assume.html) and [`assumAlso`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/sym.assumealso.html) functions.

Comment: Thank you. However, when I introduce an assumption on kmax with `assume(1>kmax)`, `isAlways(ncdf(kmax)>=0)` does not give 1 anymore. Do you know why this is the case?

Comment: Note that `assume` inherently deletes all prior assumptions on the argument variable(s). Try `assumeAlso(1>kmax)` which appends. You can run [`assumptions`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/assumptions.html) by itself to see all current assumptions that affect all variables.